# What is the number of transitive relation containing exactly three ordered pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, relations, order-theory

On a set $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ , what is the number of transitive relations, $t_{n,3}$ that contain exactly $3$ ordered pairs?

An example is the relation $\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$

I calculated the same for some values of $n$ and the same are tabulated under:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\color{red}n&\color{red}{t_{n,3}}\\
\hline
0&0\\
\hline
1&0\\
\hline
2&2\\
\hline
3&43\\
\hline
4&276\\
\hline
\end{array}

What would be a general formula for $t_{n,3}$?

Comment: I used a code to count that. Unfortunately, the code works very slowly for larger values.

Comment: @ancient mathematician, that is incorrect. You say that there are 6 of the type $\{(x,x),(x,y),(y,y)\}$. That is far from the truth. There are actually $18$ of this type- this involves choosing any two out of three having identical entries and choosing anyone out of six that have different entries.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: you missed a whole bunch of patterns: at least $\{(x,x),(y,y),(x,z)\}$, $\{(x,x),(x,y),(x,z)\}$, and $\{(x,x),(y,x),(z,x)\}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician not a good idea. now we have less examples for such relations.

Comment: What about $\{(x,x),(y,y),(z,x)\}$?

Comment: And what about $\{(x,x),(x,y),(z,y)\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $t_{n,3}$ of relations is $$t_{n,3}=\sum_{k=2}^ 6 {n \choose k} t_{k,3}$$ as we already know.
So we want to calculate $t_{n,3}, k=2,\ldots,6$. $t_{n,3}$ is the number of transitive relations on a set with $k$ elements, e.g. $\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$. If we have such a relation, e.g. $$\{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)\}$$ for n=3, we can generate other relations with the same property by renaming the elements and/or interchanging the coordinates
of such a tuple. So if we change the first and the second number of this tuple we get the relation $$\{(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)\}$$ , if we rename $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $0$, we get the relation $$\{(1,1), (1,2), (1,0)\}$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\{1,0), (1,1), (1,2)\}$$
So the set of such relations of $n$ elements can be partitioned in classes of related relations, and from one the one class element the other class elements can be generated by renaming the numbers, or interchanging the coordinates. The following table shows the a relation for each class of relations  for each number $n$ elements and the the size of the class, this is the number of differnt relations that can be generated by renameing and interchanging form the given relation. "sum" is the number of different relations of a set of $n$ different numbers.

```
N: number of different
   relations of this type

number of elements = 2      N
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1))    2
sum =                       2

number of elements = 3      N
((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2))    6
((0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1))   12
((0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 2))   12
((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2))    1
((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2))    6
sum =                      37

number of elements = 4      N
((0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 3))   48
((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3))   12
((0, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3))   24
((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3))    8
((0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 1))   24
sum =                     116

number of elements = 5      N
((0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 4))   60
((0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 4))  120
sum =                     180

number of elements = 6      N
((0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5))  120
sum =                     120
```

So finally we get
$$t_{n,3}=\frac{\left( n-1\right)  n\, \left( {{n}^{4}}-5 {{n}^{3}}+19 {{n}^{2}}-28 n+10\right)}6,\; \forall n\ge6$$

Answer (score 3):

The formula is:
$$t_{n,3} =2{n \choose 2} +  37{n \choose 3} +   116  {n \choose 4} + 180  {n \choose 5} +  120   {n \choose 6}$$

The general idea is to define $t_{n,3} = \sum_{k}d_{3,k}{n \choose k}$ where $d_{3,k}$ is the number of possible transitive relations in a set of size $k$ with exactly $3$ ordered pairs, that involve every element (ie. every element must appear in at least one pair). Then we generalize for a set of more than $k$ elements by doing a binomial of the subset of elements that do appear in pairs over the rest.

We have $3$ relations, involving no more than $6$ distinct elements, and the magic $d_{3,k}$ constants can be manually computed using a program. (tough it would be more elegant to find a solution that works without the aid of a computer).

Edit: here is the code I used to generate $d_{3,k}$ :

```
TransitiveMerge[{a_, b_}, {b_, c_}] := {{a, c}}
TransitiveMerge[{b_, c_}, {a_, b_}] := {{a, c}}
TransitiveMerge[x_, y_] := {}

TransitiveClosure[a_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort[Join[a, 
    Catenate[Map[TransitiveMerge[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Tuples[{a, a}]]]]]]

AllGraphs[n_, k_] := Subsets[Tuples[{Range[1, n], Range[1, n]}], {k}]

d[n_, k_] :=  
 d[n, k] = 
  Length[Select[
    AllGraphs[n, 
     k], (TransitiveClosure[#] === #) && 
      Length[DeleteDuplicates[Catenate[#]]] === n &]]

Comb[n_, k_] := Binomial[n, k] /; (NumberQ[n] && NumberQ[k])

t[n_, k_] := Apply[Plus, Map[Comb[n, #]* d[#, k] &, Range[1, 2*k]]]

t[n, 3]
t[n, 2]
```

Comment: Very nice work.

Comment: How exactly did you calculate $d_{3,k}$?

Comment: Exactly the same way you count $t_{k,3}$, except you only count the graphs where every element appears in some pair. For example 
$\{(1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4)\}$ is good to be counted in   $d_{4,3}$ because it is transitive and all elements $1,2,3,4$ appear in some pair. But $\{(1, 1), (1, 2), (4, 2)\}$ , even if it is counted in $t_{4,3}$, is not good to be counted in $d_{4,3}$ because, even if it is transitive, the element $3$ does not appear in any pair .  I used some code in Mathematica to  generate all possible graphs and select those that are transitive and have all elements in some pair.

Comment: Using Mathematica? Anyway thanks a lot. Will it be inappropriate if I ask you for your email?

Comment: What code did you use to count $t_{k,3}$? I can post my Mathematica code.

Comment: Kindly post it.

Comment: I have edited the answer to contain the code.

Comment: Will you kindly write a similar code for n=2?

Comment: Just replace in the code `{3}` with `{2}` and  `6` with `4` , as `6 = 2*3`  and `4 = 2*2` . You mean by $n$ the number of ordered pairs, right?

Comment: I've changed the code to just give the formula for `t[n, k]` when you give `k` as a number. It will run slow for `k>3`

Comment: May I have your email address?